# Is it possible to make referrals like example.com/username on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referrals

We want to have as much simple as possible referral links to our site for users. The best to have something like: `example.com/username`

But in this case we need to invent some way to make all other links working in WordPress. The idea how to implement it using mod_rewrite should look like:

1. If no any parameters provided - rewrite to / and process index.php
2. If parameter provided represented in site structure with file or directory - rewrite to example.com/parameter and show the content from site.
3. If link contain /s/ (`example.com/s/something`) then it's our post, which we should translate to something which allow us to see a post.
4. If one parameter provided - rewrite to `example.com/parameter` and process `example.com/index.php?ref=parameter`

Question is: Will it work for all plugins (at least woocommerce and some other) or is it possible to implement at all ? I really don't know how permalink and other wordpress part is working.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: There are modules (plugins) for this for wordpress.

Comment: Simply create a Custom Post Type or Plugin for that. No need for messing with MOD REWRITE....

Comment: But any new plugin will need to get a new parameter in URL to be called, like example.com/plugin/username but I don't want any extra to have in referral link.